# .Net MVC View not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Controller listed below:

```
//
// GET: /Customer/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(short id)
{
    ActionResult actionResult = null;

    if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        // this is the logic that is getting executed
        YeagerTechWcfService.Customer cust = db.GetCustomerID(Convert.ToInt16(id));
        actionResult = View("Details", cust);           }
    else
    {
        HttpCookie cn = Request.Cookies["strCookieName"];
        if (cn != null)
        {
            YeagerTechWcfService.Customer cust = db.GetCustomerID(Convert.ToInt16(id));
            actionResult = View("Details", cust);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["ErrCode"] = "CustView";
            actionResult = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    return actionResult;
}
```

I have a View (where the ActionLink is) like below:

```
columns.Template(
    @<text>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Detail", "Details", "Customer", new { id = item.CustomerID },
    new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "detailCustomer" })
    </text>
).Width(70);
```

The rendered output is now as follows:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#detailCustomer" href="/Customer/Details/2">Detail</a>
```

If I **click** on the link from within the source view of the browser, I get to my new View just fine.

However, if I try and click on the **ActionLink**, the View doesn't come up. I can verify during debugging, that I'm stepping thru the Details View after I hit that controller code. The present view just stays in place without switching to the new View.

Moreover, I can see that if I click on the ActionLink, it executes **the same exact code** (during debugging) **as when I paste it into the address bar**:

**http://localhost:4514/Customer/Details/2**

When I click on the ActionLink, **even though the same code is executed**, **the address url doesn't change to the above.** and the View is not being rendered.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> even though the same code is executed, the address url doesn't change
>   to the above

You are using an `Ajax.ActionLink` meaning that it will send an AJAX request. The whole point of AJAX is to stay on the same page and not redirect.

You indicate `UpdateTargetId = "detailCustomer"` so make sure that in your page you have a container with this id:

```
<div id="detailCustomer"></div>
```

which will be updated with the results of the AJAX call. Also make sure that you have properly included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page in order for the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper to do anything useful.

On the other hand if you want to perform a full postback and change the url of your browser you probably need a standard link:

```
Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Details", "Customer", new { id = item.CustomerID }, null)
```

Comment: Darin, you are absolutely correct... I completely forgot that I'm sending an AJAX request which will keep me on the same page and not redirect. I can change it to an HTML link like you suggested or perform an AJAX postback within my grid to stay on the same page. For the Details, I will do an HTML link and for the Edit, I will keep it an AJAX link and have the user perform an inline edit. Thanks so much.